# Pushing to array if value contains

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I have written

```
function arrayContains(value,array){
    var result = false;
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i]==value){
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
function someFunction(array2){
    var arr = [];
    for(i = 0 ; i<array2.length; i++){
        var val = array2[i];
        if(!arrayContains(val,arr)){
            arr.push(val);
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
}
```

But, running this code, freezes the browser. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: why don't you use just `arr.indexOf(val)==-1` instead of your function?

Comment: @Mritunjay Probably to be compatible with IE8

Comment: @dystroy does IE8 indexOf not supports indexOf()?

Comment: @Mritunjay https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `var` twice :

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){

...

for(i = 0 ; i<array2.length; i++){
```

So all your loops use the same, global, variable `i`. When you call `arrayContains`, you reset the counter used in `someFunction` which leads to that infinite loop.

Be careful to add the `var` declaration in all your loops :

```
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
```

---

Side note : you don't have to iterate over the whole array in `arrayContains`, you can do

```
function arrayContains(value, array){
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(array[i]==value) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```